# Need Whoosh step by step setup process for Django project

Tags: django, search, whoosh

I found the Whoosh search engine application which we can integrate with Django but I think it is really confusing me alot.

Is there any blog or page which explains with one example, like how Django starts with poll app.

I don't need haystack because I don't use search in UI level.

if anyone provide this info then it will be more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's bad with the [documentation of Whoosh?](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/)

Comment: Ok.. there I am unable to unserstand where do we need to write this Index writer class, how can I know it is indexing my model data?

Even I couldn't find the required settings for integrating with Django